# How to tell when I lose my EventHandler for Application.ThreadException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have an Unhandled Exception handler that does something like this:

```
  AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf Application_ThreadException
```

I was looking at what exactly this means and noticed that the decompiled code for Application shows:

```
        /// <include file='doc\Application.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Application.ThreadException"]/*' />
        /// <devdoc> 
        ///    <para>Occurs when an untrapped thread exception is thrown.</para>
        /// </devdoc>
        public static event ThreadExceptionEventHandler ThreadException {
            add { 
                Debug.WriteLineIf(IntSecurity.SecurityDemand.TraceVerbose, "AffectThreadBehavior Demanded");
                IntSecurity.AffectThreadBehavior.Demand(); 

                ThreadContext current = ThreadContext.FromCurrent();
                lock(current) { 
                    current.threadExceptionHandler = value;
                }
            }
            remove { 
                ThreadContext current = ThreadContext.FromCurrent();
                lock(current) { 
                    current.threadExceptionHandler -= value; 
                }
            } 
        }
```

So it looks like from the "add" that the last person that subscribes to Application.ThreadException is the one who gets it (it's not additive as most event handlers are). I don't want to give up my subscription to this eventhandler no matter what. Can anyone think of a way that I could track when I lose my subscription to the Application.ThreadException so I can steal it back from whoever stole it from me?

Comment: This is by design.  Having multiple events listing and, say, each display their own crash dialog is not going to work well.

Comment: @HansPassant: Do you have anything that says this is by design? The Connect issue I linked doesn't even contain a response from MS.

Comment: Just look at the source code.

Comment: @HansPassant: Clearly the source code is what it is, but that doesn't mean it was intended. For instance, `AppDomain.UnhandledException` is NOT this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking maybe I can do this with a Timer. Check if someone is already subscribed to this event and it is not me then re-subscribe. I know this is a little hackey... just thinking...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115355/application-threadexception-allows-only-one-handler-to-exist-at-a-time-it-is-incorrectly-implemented). There is no known workaround.